# How can I use additional checks in the for loop considering Hashmap?

Tags: java

I have created two hashmaps and I want to iterate both of them inside the same for loop.

```
HashMap<String,Double> hashmapA = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String,Double> hashmapB = new HashMap<>();
```

So, if I iterate the elements in `hashmapA` as follows:

```
for(String map1:hashmapA.keyset()){
...
}
```

How can I iterate the values of `hashmapB` inside the same loop? Actually, I don't want to use the inner loop.

Comment: Do they have the same keys?

Comment: Some of the keys in `hashmapB` are the same as `hashmapA`

Comment: is the question how to iterator two hashmaps in one loop ? @Hami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to iterate over all keys:

Just create a new `HashSet` out of the keys of the first `Map` and add the keys of the second `Map`:

```
Collection<Map.Entry<String,Double>> entries=new HashSet<>(hashmapA.entrySet());
keys.addAll(hashmapB.entrySet());
for(Map.Entry<String,Double> entry:entries){
    String key=entry.getKey();
    Double value=entry.getValue();
    ...
}
```

This can also be done using Java 8 Streams:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,Double> entry: Stream.concat(hashmapA.entrySet().stream(),hashmapB.entrySet().stream()){
     String key=entry.getKey();
    Double value=entry.getValue();
    ...
}
```

If you just want the intersection of the maps, you can use:

```
Collection<String> keys=new HashSet<>(hashmapA.keySet());
keys.retainAll(hashmapB.keySet());
for(String key:keys){
    Double aValue=hashmapA.get(key);
    Double bValue=hashmapB.get(key);
    ...
}
```

Or (with Streams):

```
for(String key: hashmapA.entrySet().stream().filter(k->hashmapB.containsKey(k))){
    Double aValue=hashmapA.get(key);
    Double bValue=hashmapB.get(key);
    ...
}
```

As @[bsaverino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8761466/bsaverino) stated in the comments:

> Regarding your latest remark @Hami then just iterating over the keys of `hashmapA` and using `hashmapB.containsKey(...)` could have been enough.

The following will also work in your case:

```
for(String key:hashmapA.keySet()){
    if(hashmapB.containsKey(key){
        Double aVal=hashmapA.get(key);
        Double bVal=hashmapB.get(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: As well as the Stream API may be used.

Comment: Yes, that's another possibility.

Comment: And then what to do with the values, still in separate maps. But sure its a better starting point at least.

Comment: I Fixed that :)

Comment: Actually, I want to check the keys of two maps to see if one key of `hashmapA` matches any key in `hashmapB` then do operations.

Comment: You can get the values from both sets using `retainAll`(you'll need to use `.keySet()` for this)

Comment: I've added this too.

Comment: Regarding your latest remark @Hami then just iterating over the keys of `hashmapA` and using `hashmapB.containsKey(...)` could have been enough.

Comment: Thanks for quoting me @dan1st. I hope the original (refined) question is extensively answered now.

Comment: You came up with the idea(even if I'm sure that many peaple already came up with the same idea) - You deserve the credit.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Also is it possible to write like this? `for(String map1:hashmapA.keyset() && map2:hashmapB.keyset())` . I have to iterate both maps separately but inside in a single loop.- @dan1st

Comment: @Hami Not with `&&` but you can do `for(String key: hashmapA.entrySet().stream().filter(k->hashmapB.containsKey(k))){` as I stated in my answer(edit)

Comment: Yes sure you have mentioned before. Thank you so much :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, I would appreciate you accepting it using the green tick next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Iterator is one of the best choice either with `keyset` or `entrySet`

```
Iterator hmIterator1 = hashmapA.entrySet().iterator(); 
Iterator hmIterator2 = hashmapB.entrySet().iterator(); 

 while (hmIterator1.hasNext() && hmIterator2.hasNext()) { 

       hmIterator1.next();
       hmIterator2.next();

    }
```

Comment: A necessary improvement I guess is to put an OR (||) instead of AND (&&) in the while condition and then check inside loop if each iterator .hasNext() is true before calling .next(). And by the way performing some pre-processing on the hashmaps before some iterations would sound better I believe (i.e. perform union and exclude duplicates or intersects).

Comment: I would leave that to OP either to use OR and AND condition with the logic inside of loop @bsaverino